# Нужна помощь с поиском нестатических роутов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, mvc, маршрутизация

Ради обучения пишу свой мини mvc фреймворк. Щас на роутинге.
Вот увидел как у симфони можно задать нестатический роут, сразу с доп регуляркой для параметра, и хочу реализовать подобное:

```
@Route("/test/foo/{slug}/bar/{id<\d+>}", name="test")
```

Тут, к примеру, нужно достать 2 параметра `slug`, `id`, для `slug` регулярка по умолчанию (напр. `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`), а для `id` та что в `<>`, тут будет `\d+`.

Роуты храню в таком виде:

```
$routes['get']['/contact'] = [MainController::class, 'contact'];
$routes['post']['/contact'] = [MainController::class, 'contact'];
$routes['get']['/articles/{slug}/comments/{id<\d+>}'] = [MainController::class, 'test'];
```

Статические роуты искать не проблема:

```
public function run() : Response
{
    $method = $this->request->getMethod();
    $path = $this->request->getPath();
    $params = [];

    $route = $this->routes[$method][$path] ?? false;

    if (!$route) {
        $route = $this->findUnstatic($this->routes[$method], $path, $params);
    }
    
    [$controller, $action] = $route;
    $controllerInstance = new $controller();
    
    return call_user_func([$controllerInstance, $action], $this->request , ...$params);
}
```

Нужна помощь с реализацией метода `findUnstatic($routes, $path, &$params) {}`, который вернет массив, где записан контроллер и метод для вызова, напр. `[MainController::class, 'test']`, если роут будет `/articles/{slug}/comments/{id<\d+>}`, а также запишет параметры `slug`, `id` в массив `$params`.

Comment: очевидно же, что в плане процессинга статические и "нестатические" ничем не отличаются. Роут парсится регуляркой, и в итоге превращается в нечто вроде `!^/articles/(.*?)/comments/(\d+)$!` и затем эта регулярка применяется к переданному пути.

Comment: Интересует сам процес замены `/articles/{slug}/comments/{id<\d+>}` на `/articles/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/comments/(\d+)` чтобы потом в цикле просто сопоставить.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал сам свою задачу, правда не уверен в производительности такого варианта. Если ктото знает как можно улучшить, буду рад предложениям.

```
private function findUnstatic($routes, $path, &$params)
{
    foreach ($routes as $route => $controller) {
        if (preg_match($this->routeCompile($route), $path, $params)) {
            array_shift($params);
            return $controller;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

private function routeCompile($route): string
{
    $default = '(\w+)';
    
    return preg_replace_callback('~{(.+?)}~', function ($match) use ($default) {
        return preg_match('~<(.+?)>~', $match[1], $regex)? "($regex[1])" : $default;
    }, "~^$route$~");
}
```